# Error en input file script

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

Contexto: tengo un problema en una aplicacion web hecha en spring boot, la cual el problema es que en mi vista tengo un formulario y un script para mi input en el cual tengo que adjuntar un archivo de tipo json y al precionar el boton este envia el archivo a mi controlador y realiza la ejecucion de una clase. El problema surge cuando en el input tengo el class="archivoJson" y adjunto el archivo al input y preciono el boton, el formulario llama al controlador y dispara el error: redirect:/?error=noFile pero si elimino el class del input y adjunto el archivo y ejecuto el boton este si realiza correctamente su acción.
Este es el codigo del script que consume el input para dar estilo:

```js
(function ($) {
    var customDragandDrop = function (element) {
        $(element).addClass("kwt-file__input");
        var element = $(element).wrap(
            `<div class="kwt-file"><div class="kwt-file__drop-area"><span class='kwt-file__choose-file ${
                element.attributes.data_btn_text
                    ? "" === element.attributes.data_btn_text.textContent
                        ? ""
                        : "kwt-file_btn-text"
                    : ""
            }'>${
                element.attributes.data_btn_text
                    ? "" === element.attributes.data_btn_text.textContent
                        ? `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="currentColor"><path d="..." /></svg>`
                        : `${element.attributes.data_btn_text.textContent}`
                    : `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="currentColor"><path d="..." /></svg>`
            }</span>${element.outerHTML}</span><span class="kwt-file__msg">${
                "" === element.placeholder ? "or drop files here" : `${element.placeholder}`
            }</span></div></div>`
        );
        var element = element.parents(".kwt-file");

        // Add class on focus and drag enter event.
        element.on("dragenter focus click", ".kwt-file__input", function (e) {
            $(this).parents(".kwt-file__drop-area").addClass("is-active");
        });

        // Remove class on blur and drag leave event.
        element.on("dragleave blur drop", ".kwt-file__input", function (e) {
            $(this).parents(".kwt-file__drop-area").removeClass("is-active");
        });

        // Update message text on file selection change
        element.on("change", ".kwt-file__input", function (e) {
            var textContainer = $(this).next(".kwt-file__msg");
            var files = e.target.files;
            if (files.length > 0) {
                textContainer.text(files[0].name);
                console.log("Archivo adjuntado:", files[0].name);
            } else {
                textContainer.text(
                    `${
                        "" === this[0].placeholder
                            ? "or drop files here"
                            : `${this[0].placeholder}`
                    }`
                );
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.kwtFileUpload = function (e) {
        var _this = $(this);
        $.each(_this, function (index, element) {
            customDragandDrop(element);
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

// Inicialización del plugin
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".archivoJson").kwtFileUpload();

    // Deshabilitar el script cuando se hace clic en el botón "Generar y descargar"
    $(".download-btn").click(function () {
        $(".archivoJson").off("change");
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="/generar-feature" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <input class="archivoJson" type="file" name="archivoJson"  />
        </div>
        <br>
        <button class="download-btn" type="submit">Generar y descargar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

y por ultimo este es el controlador:

```
@PostMapping("/generar-feature")
public String generarFeatureFile(@RequestParam("archivoJson") MultipartFile archivoJson, Model model) {
    if (archivoJson.isEmpty()) {
        // Manejar el caso en el que no se haya seleccionado ningún archivo
        return "redirect:/?error=noFile";
    }

    try {
        // Leer el contenido del archivo JSON
        String jsonContent = new String(archivoJson.getBytes());

        // Crear una instancia de FeatureFileGeneratorCollection y pasarle el contenido JSON
        FeatureFileGeneratorCollection generator = new FeatureFileGeneratorCollection(jsonContent);

        // Generar el archivo de características
        String featureFileName = "feature_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".feature";
        String filePath = FEATURE_FILES_DIRECTORY + featureFileName;
        generator.generateFeatureFile(filePath);

        model.addAttribute("featureFileName", featureFileName);
        return "redirect:/descargar-feature/" + featureFileName;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Manejar errores de lectura o escritura de archivos
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "redirect:/?error=ioError";
    }
}
```

Haber si alguien me puede dar una mano con el error.